# Is it possible to have a std::vector of struct with a fexible array member?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, flexible-array-member

I have a struct with a flexible array member that I need to use.

```
struct Record
{
     uint32_t length;
     Data contents[];
};
```

I'm able to initialize this and use it by doing something like this: (it would also work with malloc or any other dynamic allocation)

```
vector<Data> members;
vector<uint8_t> buffer;
Record myRecord;
buffer.resize(sizeof(Record) + members.size() * sizeof(Data));
myRecord = *(reinterpret_cast<Record*>(buffer.data());
myRecord.length = static_cast<uint32_t>(members.size());
// copy members to myRecord.contents
```

That works just fine. But now I need to have an interface that operates on batches of Record, and I have been trying to use an std::vector for this. Then problems start appearing, and I'm guessing it's because std::vector arranges all elements contiguously on memory, and since sizeof(Record) won't take into account the size of the contents (each vector element will hold only 4 bytes, instead of 4 bytes + size_of_contents * sizeof(Data)), the vector elements are actually sharing memory and then each element starts overwriting the contents of the previous element. Does that make sense?

If this really is the problem, I was wondering if there's any way to "force" the vector to allocate a specific size for each element (instead of whatever sizeof returns for the element's type). That way I could make sure that each vector element would have enough size. If that's not possible, is there an alternative solution? Maybe a different container that would allow me to do so? Please keep in mind that I *do* need to use the struct as it's defined (I would love to just replace the whole thing for a vector but unfortunately that's not possible)

Comment: You didn't mention the problems that *started appearing*

Comment: See tag-wiki (http://stackoverflow.com/tags/flexible-array-member/info): That feature is part of C99+, not C++. Also, please refrain from ever mistagging a C++ question as a C one. Now, Some gnu++ dialects might combine those...

Comment: @rgoliveira I meant to say that data started getting inconsistent.

Comment: Why you say you must use the struct in its current form?

Comment: Try replacing the "flexible array" with `std::vector`.

Comment: If `// copy members to myRecord.contents` part does what I think it does, it happily trashes the stack: it's a stack-based buffer overrun. `sizeof(myRecord)` didn't magically change when you assigned to `myRecrod.length`. There's space for exactly zero elements in `myRecord.contents`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: "*Why you say you must use the struct in its current form?*" Probably because he's interfacing with some C system and he therefore doesn't have control of the interface. Does it matter?

Comment: Work with `std::vector<Data>` in your own code (you can have a vector of those vectors). Repack into a suitably allocated instance of `Record` whenever you need to interface with the system that requires it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your principle problem is this:

```
myRecord = *(reinterpret_cast<Record*>(buffer.data());
```

That's simply overwriting the data in a stack variable. That does not change the address of `myRecord` to suddenly point to `buffer.data()`. Which means when you later do `myRecord.contents[...] = ...`, you're going to be trashing the stack.

What you almost certainly intended was:

```
Record *myRecord = (reinterpret_cast<Record*>(buffer.data());
```

Then you would have a pointer to memory managed by `buffer`, which would have sufficient storage for the `myRecord->contents` array.

You *cannot* treat `Record` like a value type. As far as C++'s object model is concerned, it's not a value type. It cannot be copied or moved like most C++ types. You can only manipulate it through a pointer/reference to the specific allocation you use here.

That being said, using a `vector` to manage the storage for your `Record*` like this is really weird. It'd be better to use a `unique_ptr`, since resizing the allocation would be a really bad idea.

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> storage = new char[sizeof(Record) + (members.size() * sizeof(Data))];
```

This also prevents the system from initializing the memory, since you're going to overwrite it anyway.

> I was wondering if there's any way to "force" the vector to allocate a specific size for each element (instead of whatever sizeof returns for the element's type).

No. `vector` manages a contiguous array of elements of the same type. And in C++, all objects of the same type have the same size.

Comment: Just as the OP cannot have a Record on the stack, the vector simply needs to be a vector of (smart) pointers

Comment: @Yakk: I get the impression that the `vector<Data>` is there to actually be the source of the data within his application. But when he needs to talk to the C code, he needs to convert it into a flexible array member. So he doesn't need to store the `Record` objects long-term. At least, that's the sense I get from the question.

Comment: @NicolBolas Thanks. But I hit the same problem when trying to add to the vector. If I manage the storage through *myRecord as you suggested and then try to push_back(*myRecord) or assign *myRecord to a vector element, data is still somehow corrupted.

Comment: @DerekPatton: That's because you keep trying to *copy* the `Record`. `Record` is effectively non-copyable; you can *only* deal with it by pointer or reference. If you want to have an array of `Record`s, then it must be a `vector<Record*>`.